# How to scrape reddit data by Python based on a time range & topic

Tags: python, web-scraping, sentiment-analysis, reddit

How can I scrape Reddit content/headline to do sentiment analysis?
I want to collect covid - related and the time range based on 2020 Jan 1 to 2022 Mar 1.
Thanks!

Comment: you can use modules `request`/`urllib` to get HTML, and `BeautifulSoup`/`lxml` to search element in HTML. But first you should check if reddit has API for programmers and maybe it gives access to data as JSON without scraping. You should also first check if there is some module to work w reddit.

Comment: [Reddit API](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/) and [PRAW: The Python Reddit API Wrapper](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.